# How to merge 2 or more Transactions and ask for 1 time payment only

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, candy-machine-v2, cargo

Edited:
I want to merge the following 2 Transactions. Not sure if it will be done from the front-end or in the rust program.

Transaction 1 -> Mint NFT token:

[image]

Transaction 2 -> Collect NFT in wallet:

[image]

```
pub fn mint_nft(
    ctx: Context<MintNFT>,
    creator_key: Pubkey,
    uri: String,
    title: String,
) -> Result<()> {
    //msg!("initializating PDA variables to 0 value");
    let ledger_account = &mut ctx.accounts.ledger_account;
  
    // minting 
if  ledger_account.count < 1000 {
    msg!("Initializing Mint NFT");
    let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
    };
    msg!("CPI Accounts Assigned");
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    msg!("CPI Program Assigned");
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    msg!("CPI Context Assigned");
    token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
    msg!("Token Minted !!!");
    let account_info = vec![
        ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    ];
    msg!("Account Info Assigned");
    let creator = vec![
        mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
            address: creator_key,
            verified: false,
            share: 100,
        },
        mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
            address: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
            verified: false,
            share: 0,
        },
    ];
    msg!("Creator Assigned");
    let symbol = std::string::ToString::to_string("symb");
    // let new_uri = format!("{}{}{}",ctx.accounts.minting_account.base_uri, ctx.accounts.minting_account.cur_num , ".json");
    let new_uri = format!("{}{}{}", uri, ctx.accounts.ledger_account.count, ".json");

    invoke(
        &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            title,
            symbol,
            new_uri,
            Some(creator),
            1,
            true,
            false,
            None,
            None,
        ),
        account_info.as_slice(),
    )?;
    msg!("Metadata Account Created !!!");
    let master_edition_infos = vec![
        ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
    ];
    msg!("Master Edition Account Infos Assigned");
    invoke(
        &create_master_edition_v3(
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
            ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            Some(0),
        ),
        master_edition_infos.as_slice(),
    )?;
    msg!("Master Edition Nft Minted !!!");
}
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest solution is to send both instructions in the same transaction on the front end. The wallet preview you are looking at would show the result of the entire tx, with both operations.

Comment: You can use signAllTransactions method from @solana/wallet-adapter-react. It is explained by Solandy [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oe9y0UFhU1Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it both from a Front-end and Program Level.I am assuming you want to take some payment for minting of the NFT that can be done by adding a transfer CPI call in the above code or a transfer ix in the front-end.